# usb key keeps disconnecting

Tags: usb, disconnect

Machine : Dell XPS 2020 9300 (2 weeks old)
I have a set of 3 Kingston Keys that keep disconnecting on the machine.

I have many USB keys and only those three Kingston keys show the problem
So it seems the problem is the keys

I have a Corsair 128 Gb key that works fine
A dozen keys from various manufacturers, from 4 to 32 Gb, all work fine

But those Kingston keys keep disconnecting/reconnecting
Model is : Kingston DataTraveler 100G3 32 Gb
Sold by a pack of 3

In the kern.log I see this :

```
May 20 10:57:04 asgard kernel: [ 1543.950250] usb-storage 2-3:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
May 20 10:57:04 asgard kernel: [ 1543.950772] scsi host1: usb-storage 2-3:1.0
May 20 10:57:05 asgard kernel: [ 1544.964999] scsi 1:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Kingston DataTraveler 3.0      PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
May 20 10:57:05 asgard kernel: [ 1544.965560] sd 1:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
May 20 10:57:05 asgard kernel: [ 1544.966042] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] 60437492 512-byte logical blocks: (30.9 GB/28.8 GiB)
May 20 10:57:05 asgard kernel: [ 1544.966369] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
May 20 10:57:05 asgard kernel: [ 1544.966371] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 4f 00 00 00
May 20 10:57:05 asgard kernel: [ 1544.966618] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: disabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
May 20 10:57:05 asgard kernel: [ 1544.969216]  sda: sda1
May 20 10:57:05 asgard kernel: [ 1544.970203] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI removable disk
May 20 10:57:12 asgard kernel: [ 1551.635198] usb 2-3: USB disconnect, device number 10
May 20 10:57:12 asgard kernel: [ 1551.635303] xhci_hcd 0000:00:0d.0: WARN Set TR Deq Ptr cmd failed due to incorrect slot or ep state.
May 20 10:57:12 asgard kernel: [ 1551.983547] usb 2-3: new SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 11 using xhci_hcd
May 20 10:57:12 asgard kernel: [ 1552.016767] usb 2-3: New USB device found, idVendor=0951, idProduct=1666, bcdDevice= 0.01
May 20 10:57:12 asgard kernel: [ 1552.016770] usb 2-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
May 20 10:57:12 asgard kernel: [ 1552.016772] usb 2-3: Product: DataTraveler 3.0
May 20 10:57:12 asgard kernel: [ 1552.016774] usb 2-3: Manufacturer: Kingston
May 20 10:57:12 asgard kernel: [ 1552.016775] usb 2-3: SerialNumber: 60A44C413E29F3A0F6314B78
May 20 10:57:12 asgard kernel: [ 1552.025911] usb-storage 2-3:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
May 20 10:57:12 asgard kernel: [ 1552.026349] scsi host0: usb-storage 2-3:1.0
May 20 10:57:13 asgard kernel: [ 1553.427146] usb 2-3: USB disconnect, device number 11
May 20 10:57:13 asgard kernel: [ 1553.427267] xhci_hcd 0000:00:0d.0: WARN Set TR Deq Ptr cmd failed due to incorrect slot or ep state.
May 20 10:57:14 asgard kernel: [ 1553.739518] usb 2-3: new SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 12 using xhci_hcd
May 20 10:57:14 asgard kernel: [ 1553.772639] usb 2-3: New USB device found, idVendor=0951, idProduct=1666, bcdDevice= 0.01
May 20 10:57:14 asgard kernel: [ 1553.772643] usb 2-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
May 20 10:57:14 asgard kernel: [ 1553.772645] usb 2-3: Product: DataTraveler 3.0
May 20 10:57:14 asgard kernel: [ 1553.772647] usb 2-3: Manufacturer: Kingston
May 20 10:57:14 asgard kernel: [ 1553.772649] usb 2-3: SerialNumber: 60A44C413E29F3A0F6314B78
May 20 10:57:14 asgard kernel: [ 1553.782174] usb-storage 2-3:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
May 20 10:57:14 asgard kernel: [ 1553.782432] scsi host0: usb-storage 2-3:1.0
May 20 10:57:15 asgard kernel: [ 1554.788995] scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Kingston DataTraveler 3.0      PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
May 20 10:57:15 asgard kernel: [ 1554.789371] sd 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
May 20 10:57:15 asgard kernel: [ 1554.789937] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 60437492 512-byte logical blocks: (30.9 GB/28.8 GiB)
May 20 10:57:15 asgard kernel: [ 1554.790246] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
May 20 10:57:15 asgard kernel: [ 1554.790248] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 4f 00 00 00
May 20 10:57:15 asgard kernel: [ 1554.790487] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: disabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
May 20 10:57:15 asgard kernel: [ 1554.793073]  sda: sda1
May 20 10:57:15 asgard kernel: [ 1554.794133] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI removable disk
May 20 10:57:15 asgard kernel: [ 1554.992138] FAT-fs (sda1): Volume was not properly unmounted. Some data may be corrupt. Please run fsck.
May 20 10:57:20 asgard kernel: [ 1559.756167] usb 2-3: USB disconnect, device number 12
```

It keeps disconnecting and reconnecting all the time.

I guess those keys are defective in some way.
What should I do ? Report this a bug ?

Log seems to report something wrong :

May 20 10:57:12 asgard kernel: [ 1551.635303] xhci_hcd 0000:00:0d.0: WARN Set TR Deq Ptr cmd failed due to incorrect slot or ep state.